# Date comparison using Mongo queries

Tags: mongodb

I want to display Equal to or lesser than or greater than, today's date document from my address collection

I'm using a mongo `$eq` query.

This is address schema structure

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Addressschema = mongoose.Schema({
    user_id : {type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'user'},
    lane_1: { type: String, default: '' },
    lane_2: { type: String, default: '' },
    district: { type: String, default: '' },
    state: { type: String, default: ''},
    country: { type: String, default: '' },
    pincode: { type: Number, default: '' },
    defaulttype : {type : Boolean,default : true},
    created_date: { type: Date, default: new Date() },
    modified_date: { type: Date, default: new Date() },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('address', Addressschema, 'address');
```

This is my code to find document

```
addressDB.find({"created_date" : { $eq : new Date().toISOString()} }).exec((err ,data)=>{
            console.log(data);
        });
```

and my output is empty array(  []  )

I don't know how to handle mongo queries and I'm new to node js, please anyone help me fix my code

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB comparison operators are type-aware.

The schema specifies that `created_date` is type `Date`, but `new Date().toISOString()` is a string.

MongoDB internally stores datetime as milliseconds since epoch.
The default value for `created_date` is `new Date()`, which is also at millisecond resolution.

Querying with `$eq` will only match if the date in the document is exactly the same millisecond being queried.

Comment: im also try to find without convert into string still im getting empty array..plz gave me any other suggestion or any other way

Comment: Unless you are trying to match the exact time, including millisecond, you will need to either 1) test with `$gt` and `$lt` instead of `$eq` (can use index) or 2) use aggregation to extract the date from the timestamp and compare on that (cannot use index)